# Coldfusion HQL query exception - unexpected token

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, lucee

Under `Lucee 4.5.1`, using Coldfusion/HQL, I'm getting the following error:

```
Lucee 4.5.1.022 Error (org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException)
Message     unexpected token: : near line 1, column 88 [from League where leagueID in (select leagueID from Game where seasonID=:sid and userID:=uid and showReportYN=1) order by leagueID]
Cause   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException
Stacktrace  The Error Occurred in
/my/file/code.cfm: line 39
...
39: qryLeagues = ORMExecuteQuery("from League where leagueID in (select leagueID from Game where seasonID=:sid and userID:=uid and showReportYN=1) order by leagueID", {sid=url.sid, uid=request.userID});
...
```

It seems to match the HQL documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3400

And, this SO post, seems to also indicate that it's ok:
[unexpected token : ( subquery hql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30857140/unexpected-token-subquery-hql)

Not sure what I'm missing...

**Update #2**

Answer did fix it, but then got the following error:

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode
```

Here is the final working query (note class aliases in sub query):

```
qryLeagues = ORMExecuteQuery("from League where leagueID in (select g.League.leagueID from Game g where g.Season.seasonID=:sid and g.Season.User.userID=:uid and g.League.showReportYN=1)",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `=` and `:` switched in your second param (at the 88th character)

```
and userID:=uid
```

should be

```
and userID=:uid
```

with the `=` first then then `:`